SqlClient error or authentication error randomly occurring of different application. Azure SQL Server database
Sometimes I see those errors in the logs and we are not able to understand which may be the root cause:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OnFedAuthInfo(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Projects\repos\xxx\Program.cs:line 21

or

MoonshineExceptionFilter -> Handled exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Operation cancelled by user.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__211_0(Task1 result)   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func4 operation, Func4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

We are running the SQL Server on Azure from an Elastic Pool that has 2 Database (the main one and an Hangfire one).
The sizing of the elastic pool is
.
We are using integrated auth to connect to SQL Server and we have this error occurring randomly on different apps.
We checked and the connection seems to be released, we are using on some products Linq2db with DI context and in other application we are using Entity Framework Core DataContext, always injected via DI.
Is there any possible cause or a way to diagnose it?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

"A severe error occurred on the current command" is a sign that something went serously wrong with SQL Server, and there will usually be a stack dump on the server. Given you are using SQL Azure, you should probably report it to them, as you can't debug the server. It is always possible it could be intermittent network issues, you should ionvestigate that as well.

We have been noticing a lot of connection issues from our web apps running nopcommerce towards azure sql dbs. I have contacted microsoft and they are checking it up. We have not done any code changes recently, but its a problem on 10+ web apps, using 5 different sql dbs.

@sindrem Are you the OP? if so you should not have two different accounts. Like I said, you should report to MS, I don't think there is anything we can do to diagnose this.

No, i'm not - i just wanted to add that we have the same issue.
